# PHP: Split string into chunks of 8, how do I do this?

Tags: php, function, arrays, binary, chunks

I have binary basically, say it's 300 in length. How would I split (much like using explode) it into 8 bit chunks? I look at *chunk_split()* but it only seems to have an 'end' parameter, not an option to put it into an array.. Or can it be socketed into an array?

The end 8 digits can be below 8 (in case a miscopy from someone, and it's 4) so no validation is needed, just consistantly in 8 number chunks from the start to end.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`str_split`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php):

```
$chunks = str_split($data, 8);
```

Comment: Thanks, wasn't sure it could be done this way, saves me a lot of time! +1